# При отправке формы вывести на экран окно "Заявка отправлена"

Tags: php, html

Ребята привет! При отправки заявки, браузер переходит на пустой php файл где содержится скрипт отправки формы, при это форма рабочая но хотелось бы что бы всплывало окно о успешной отправке или хотя бы просто обновлялась страничка.
Заранее огромное спасибо!

```
<div class="popup reg_form">
    <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
    <h2>ОТПРАВИТЬ ЗАЯВКУ</h2>
    <form id="contactForm" class="contact-form" method="post" action="contact_mailer.php">
                                    <div class="form-group form-icon-group">
                                        <input class="form-control" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Ваше Имя*" type="text" required>
                                        <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group form-icon-group">
                                        <input class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Ваш e-mail*" type="email" required>
                                        <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group form-icon-group">
                                        <input class="form-control" name="phone" placeholder="Контактный телефон*" type="text" required>
                                        <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
                                    </div>

                                    <div>
                                        <input type="submit" value="Отправить заявку" class="btn btn-danger scroll-to-id ">
                                    </div>
    </form>


<?php
if((isset($_POST['name'])&&$_POST['name']!="")&&(isset($_POST['email'])&&$_POST['email']!="")&&(isset($_POST['phone'])&&$_POST['phone']!="")){

$to = 'godofwar9325@gmail.com'; //Почта получателя, через запятую можно указать сколько угодно адресов
        $subject = 'Обратный звонок'; //Загаловок сообщения
        $message = '
                <html>
                    <head>
                        <title>'.$subject.'</title>
                    </head>
                    <body>
                        <p><b>Имя:</b> '.$_POST['name'].'</p>
                        <p><b>Телефон:</b> '.$_POST['phone'].'</p> 
                         <p><b>Почта:</b> '.$_POST['email'].'</p>                         
                    </body>
                </html>'; //Текст нащего сообщения можно использовать HTML теги
        $headers  = "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8 \r\n"; //Кодировка письма
        $headers .= "From: Отправитель <uber-key.ru>\r\n"; //Наименование и почта отправителя
        mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); //Отправка письма с помощью функции mail


}?>




<?php
if((isset($_POST['name'])&&$_POST['name']!="")&&(isset($_POST['email'])&&$_POST['email']!="")&&(isset($_POST['phone'])&&$_POST['phone']!="")){

$to = 'godofwar9325@gmail.com'; //Почта получателя, через запятую можно указать сколько угодно адресов
        $subject = 'Обратный звонок'; //Загаловок сообщения
        $message = '
                <html>
                    <head>
                        <title>'.$subject.'</title>
                    </head>
                    <body>
                        <p><b>Имя:</b> '.$_POST['name'].'</p>
                        <p><b>Телефон:</b> '.$_POST['phone'].'</p> 
                         <p><b>Почта:</b> '.$_POST['email'].'</p>                         
                    </body>
                </html>'; //Текст нащего сообщения можно использовать HTML теги
        $headers  = "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8 \r\n"; //Кодировка письма
        $headers .= "From: Отправитель <uber-key.ru>\r\n"; //Наименование и почта отправителя

        mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

     if(mail(@params)){ //та самая проверка ответа mail(); из коммента
    header('Location: uber-key.ru/index.html');
}else{
    header('Location: uber-key.ru/failed.html');
}
index.html
  echo 'main send successfully';

failed.html
   echo 'main didnt send becouse of ...';


}?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После строки `mail($to, $subject, $message,......`
Добавить `echo "<h2>Заявка отправлена</h2>";`

Comment: Спасибо огромное, все получилось.

Comment: а можно как то сделать что бы браузер возвращал на главную после echo ?

Comment: а если заявка не отправлена? проверки нет. хотя бы if()

Comment: Кирилл можно поподробнее?

Comment: Еще есть один нюанс, на apple устройствах надпись выводится кракозябрами, как можно исправить?

Comment: кракозябры потому, что кодировка для файла обработчика не установлена. а вы в нём и эхаете (по первому комменту).

Comment: так как можно поправить?)

Comment: @АнтонРодионов, лучше задавать отдельными вопросами. Один вопрос - один топик. По вопросу с крякозабами стоит добавить заголовок с кодировкой. Ответ как это сделать отлично описан тут http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4279282/set-http-header-to-utf-8-using-php

Answer (score 1):

В вашем случае есть несколько способов решения поставленной задачи.

**Первый** и самый очевидный (но не самый лучший) - перенаправление пользователя после отправки письма на страницу сообщения об удачной или неудачной отправке. Обычно это реализуют так:

```
if(mail(@params)){ //та самая проверка ответа mail(); из коммента
    header('Location: http://yoursite.com/success.html');
}else{
    header('Location: http://yoursite.com/failed.html');
}

success.html
  echo 'main send successfully';

failed.html
   echo 'main didn't send becouse of ...';
```

Можете так же возвращаться на исходную страницу (где заполняли форму) с get-маркером отправки письма:

```
if(mail(@params)){
    header('Location: http://where_you_came_from.com?m=1');
}
```

Тогда в исходном файле будете проверять $_get:

```
if($_get && isset($_get['m'])){ 
    echo ($_get['m']) ? 'блок с сообщением об отправке письма' : 'блок с сообщением об ошибке отправки'.
}
```

Таким методом можно перенаправить юзера на любую страницу, в зависимости от ваших нужд. А про вывод сообщений в файле-обработчике просто забудьте, по мере изучения языка и шаблонов программирования всё станет на свои места, пока просто запомните(имхо).

**Второй** способ обработки - **ajax**, это js. Очень рекомендую изучать.

Отдельно хочу обратить ваше внимание на обработку данных, приходящих из форм. В вашем примере вы без обработки отправляете данные в функцию. В случае с письмом это не так важно, но когда в дальнейшем вы начнёте работу с бд, такое будет непростительно.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ! Я попробывал первый способ но почему то не выщло, код вставил в впорос

Comment: header отправляйте через абсолютную ссылку header('Location: http(s)://uber-key.ru/index.html');